# Why does current in an $RC$ circuit become zero when the capacitor is fully charged?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Consider an $RC$ circuit with one resistor in series with a capacitor. We know that a capacitor takes sometime to become fully charged. Current flows during that duration and the capacitor gets charged. But after it has been fully charged (to the magnitude of it's Capacitance*Applied Voltage), no current flows through the circuit at all. Why is that? I mean current should keep flowing right and after sometime there should be a dielectric breakdown and the capacitor should break down? Why does no current flow at all after the capacitor has been charged?

Answer (score 4):

because when the cap is fully charged, the voltage across it *equals the source voltage*. because they are equal, no voltage difference exists and hence no current flows.

Answer (score 0):

Under constant voltage conditions (cv generator) the current stops because the voltage difference between the generator and the capacitor reaches zero. Under constant current conditions (cc generator) current continues to flow and a spark from the capacitor can be observed, this is dielectric bread-down. This is a standard high school experiment that I did and remember very well.

Answer (score 0):

You never said what caused current to flow in the first place.

If the current is driven by a [*voltage source*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source), then the circuit will behave as described in Niels Nielsen's answer: The flowing current will cause the voltage on the capacitor to rise, but because of Kirchoff's Voltage Law, the sum of the resistor voltage and the capacitor voltage and the source voltage must be zero. When the capacitor voltage eventually becomes equal and opposite to the battery voltage, then there's nothing left for the resistor, and when the resistor voltage is zero, Ohm's Law tells us that the current must be zero.

We often just *assume* that a power supply acts as a voltage source. Most electronic circuits are designed to be powered by a voltage source (or sometimes, by more than one voltage source.) That's because a battery is a good approximation of a voltage source, and the power coming from an electrical generating station is an excellent approximation of a voltage source. *BUT*...

...If the source in the circuit you described was a [*current source*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source), then the current in the circuit would, by definition, remain constant, and the capacitor voltage would continue to rise forever or until the capacitor blew up (whichever came first.)

We study current sources because in many practical electronic circuits, a transistor can be modelled as a current-controlled or voltage-controlled current source. Also, there are some devices (LED lamps, electroplating setups, IDK what else) for which it is easier/better to control the current instead of trying to control the voltage.